# Backup to VM strategy: sysprep doubts

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, sysprep

I'm considering this strategy: backing up an old, but important computer to a VM, doing a **P2V conversion**.

I would use **Hyper-V** and the conversion would be done with SysInternals **Disk2VHD** utility. The PC is a 2007 laptop with Vista (yes...) and about 200 programs installed.

My purpose is to **keep using the original PC until it dies** (there are some signs of problems). When it does, the VM will be used to recover some files. The fact that it is a VM that I can power up (instead of just a "dead" backup) is important because running the installed software makes it easier to work with the data to move it to a newer system (exports, conversions, etc.).

I'm told the system will have to be **generalized with sysprep before the P2V conversion**, so it can later boot in different hardware inside the VM.

But I have doubts about sysprepping the original computer, which I intend to continue using normally. Most sysprep documentation online (understandably) is for people doing mass production of systems, where the processes and the concerns are quite different from mine.

So my questions are these:

1. If I sysprep the original computer before using Disk2VHD, **what will happen to this original computer**? Will I just have a longer reboot, with drivers reinstalling, or will I somehow break things (eg Windows license, user settings, etc)?
2. If this strategy sounds dangerous or problematic, is there **another similar strategy that might work**? Specifically, I would love to be able to **sysprep the offline VHD file only *after* the conversion**, thus leaving the original computer untouched. But I doubt this is possible.

P.S. - regarding Windows licenses, I don't need to keep using the VM for long, or re-Activate Windows in the VM: as long as it runs occasionally and I can grab what I need, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

If both "machines" do not need to function simultaneously as part of a domain you do not necessarily need to sysprep at all. Just give it a  go without sysprepping first and see what driver issues if any you run into.

If you hit the STOP 0x0000007B INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE problem you will need to make sure the drivers for IDE are loaded in the image. It is easier to do this on the physical machine before you P2V rather than try to inject them into the image.

Adapted from http://blogs.technet.com/b/michs/archive/2011/09/16/p2v-migration-issues-with-hyper-v-stop-0x0000007b.aspx:

- Confirm Files Exist (if not you can extract them from `C:\windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\mshdc.inf_amd64_neutral_552ea5111ec825a6`)

  - `windows\system32\drivers\intelide.sys`
  - `windows\system32\drivers\pciide.sys`
  - `windows\system32\drivers\atapi.sys`
- Confirm Registry Entries Exist

  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\CriticalDeviceDatabase\pci#ven_8086&dev_7111`
  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\CriticalDeviceDatabase\pci#ven_8086&dev_7110&cc_0601`
  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\CriticalDeviceDatabase\primary_ide_channel`
  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\CriticalDeviceDatabase\secondary_ide_channel`
  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\IntelIde`
  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\PCIIde`
  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\atapi`

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion. Disk2VHD is running, it will take quite a few hours...

Comment: I get a Bluescreen 0x000007B (INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE). I feared exactly this would happen, I had this experience with cloning Vista from an old hard disk to an SSD and I could never get it running without sysprep because of these disk driver incompatibilities... I guess I'm back to my original question...

Comment: Ok, it was worth a try. Much of the time you can anticipate and resolve these driver issues on the physical machine before taking the image, still without the need for sysprep. Let me research a little and I will update the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I've now tried that site and a handful of others with recommendations involving offline editing of the registry, but I always get the BSOD.

Comment: I was suggesting to do it on the physical PC (before taking another image) rather than trying to offline-edit the image. Did you try that? Should not be that risky as you are only adding drivers not removing/changing any.

Comment: Yes, I edited the registry on the VHD by mounting it. 
For me, the risky thing would be to mess with the original system which I already know to be picky with disk drivers due to all my troubles when I cloned the system onto a new SSD (that's where I learned offline registry editing! But the only thing that eventually saved me was a sysprep before cloning).
Trying things on the vhdx isn't risky at all, I can keep copies, do snapshots, etc.

Comment: Then, I am not so sure how to proceed. I guess you could take a _restorable_ image of the physical disk with something like Clonezilla or Ghost, then you can sysprep and P2V as much as you want, then restore from that the original image if you find the changes made by sysprep (de-activation etc.) are causing you more than temporary issues.

Comment: The drivers should exist within Windows, the item you need to set is the Start key under the driver in CurrentControlSet should be set to 0 for each storage driver (MSAHCI/IASTORV/etc.)

I think it’d be very unlikely that Windows does not contain a driver compatible with your VM, it just needs to be enabled.

You could also try switching the VHD from an IDE to a SCSI device or vice versa.

Comment: @WinOutreach2: I've done extensive attempts with this sort of thing but I can never get it right. I've tried enabling and disabling drivers, copying files around, copying registry settings from a working system (a clean Vista install inside a VM). I've also tried the IDE/SCSI variation. But I feel I'm working blindly. I should know exactly which driver is crashing my VM, but I never find any way to get that information...